# How to call a method of uiview class in mainViewController in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I make a method `setupLabels` in a custom uiview class and i, m trying to call this method in mainViewController `viewDidLoad` method using `[self setupLabels]` but i gives error of undefined setupLabels, How can i access `-(void)setUpLabels{` method from a uiview class into mainviewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error because your `setUpLabels` method is in your custom class and `ViewController` doesn't have the reference to it. You need to provide reference to use method on other classes.

Firstly you need to make an object of your custom UIView class.
Put your method `-(void)setUpLabels` in `.h` file of your custom view class. Implement it in `.m` of your custom class.

Now in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller based on the type of your Custom Class you have to create Object of that view:

If you are using xib:

```
   MyCustomView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
   [customView  setUpLabels];
```

If not using Xib

```
   MyCustomView *customView =  [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
   [customView  setUpLabels];
```

At last in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        MyCustomView *customView =  [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
        customView.frame = CGRectMake(100,10,200,100);
        [customView  setUpLabels];
        [self.view addSubview:customView];
   }
```

Comment: @Moon please show us the code how and where you are adding labels.

Comment: my custum view class name is labels and i make a method in it as here-(void)setupLabels{
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 70, 50)];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self addSubview:lbl];
    
}
after that i call in viewdidload  as labels *customView =  [[labels alloc] init];
    [customView setupLabels];

Comment: are you adding custom view into self.view?? and also you need to give frame to your customView befor adding to seLf.view

Comment: you mean to create a frame as a subview ?

Comment: yeah i marked it and can u please help me a bit more as i have another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142796/discussion-between-rahulmishra-and-moon).